# How to create an empty file from an empty diff using the patch utility?

Tags: linux, diff, patch

I have an output from `diff -au` (if it matters, this command is used within `svn diff`), like:

> Index: src/test.txt
>    ===================================================================

It's a newly created empty file.
How can I force patch utility to create this empty file?

Comment: Your diff is not empty. I've the same issue, and my diff has some lines more but no file is being created by patching (via TortoiseSVN).

Comment: What command was used generating the diff file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way, except patching the `patch` utility in upstream.

Comment: Any references for that?